# How do i display the data i got from an api through a button click?

Tags: javascript, angular, button

I have managed to get data from an API and display it on-screen when the page loads, but I don't know how to display it through a button click. How do I do this?

This is my component.ts file

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'NewProjectAdnan';
  
  private apiUrl = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json';
  bitcoinData: any = {};

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('hello fellow user!')
    //this.getData();
    //dthis.getContacts();
}

getData(){

  var myHttpObservable = this.http.get( this.apiUrl );

 return myHttpObservable.pipe(
    map((bitcoinData) => {
                return bitcoinData;
              }))
    }

    
    getContacts(){
      this.getData().subscribe(bitcoinData => {
        console.log(bitcoinData);
        this.bitcoinData=bitcoinData
      })
    }
  }
```

this is my HTML file

```html
<body>
  <button >get bitcoin price</button>
  <div id="myDiv"> The bitcoin rate for the date {{ bitcoinData.time.updated }} is {{ bitcoinData.bpi.USD.rate }} 
    {{ bitcoinData.bpi.USD.code }}. </div>
</body>
```

I am on angular 8.

Comment: Just create an event listener for the button click, and attach it to your existing function.

Comment: Just call getData() from button, <button onClick='getData'>

Answer (score 1):

Add click event to your button to call your getData() function

```html
<body>
  <button (click)="getData()">get bitcoin price</button>
  <div id="myDiv"> The bitcoin rate for the date {{ bitcoinData.time.updated }} is {{ bitcoinData.bpi.USD.rate }} 
    {{ bitcoinData.bpi.USD.code }}. </div>
</body>
```